# How to handle NumberPicker Value change?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have a `NumberPicker` that contains titles of games.
The thing is I want that in each time a person scroll the `NumberPicker` and stops at one of the titles, I will be able to immediately handle this action and fill 2 `EditText` with information I want.

On button press there is `void onClick(View view)` that handles each time a `Button` is pressed on a view, How do I do a similar thing with `NumberPicker`?

This is my code:

```
NumberPicker picker;
SharedPreferences sp;
String JsonDataGL;
String[] arrayGL;
ProgressDialog p;
GamesLibrary[] gamesArray;
String Count = "0";
EditText gameTitleET, gameContentET;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);
    sp=getSharedPreferences("JsonData", 0);
    JsonDataGL = sp.getString("JsonGL", null);

    gameTitleET = findViewById(R.id.GameTitleET); //The 2 EditTexts I want to fill with text
    gameContentET = findViewById(R.id.GameTitleET);

    JSONObject json_data = null;
    try {
        json_data = new JSONObject(JsonDataGL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Count = json_data.getString("count");
        Log.d("Nugi32", Count);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gamesArray = new GamesLibrary[Integer.parseInt(Count)];

    picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(Integer.parseInt(Count)-1);
    arrayGL = new String[Integer.parseInt(Count)];
    DownLoadJsonGL downLoadJsonGL = new DownLoadJsonGL();
    downLoadJsonGL.execute(JsonDataGL); //Here The NumberPicker is filled with the titles

}
```

Do you have any idea how can I do that? or lead me to tutorial online?
Because I couldn't find anything concerns to this topic online.
Thank you!

Comment: you will have to create your own numberpicker for that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: ok, looks like there is a way as for @ZeekHuge answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation for `NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setOnValueChangedListener(android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener)) shows,
you can use

```
picker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){
                //Process the changes here
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the on value change listener for this purpose ? It will be called when value changes in number picker.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener.html

```
void onValueChange (NumberPicker picker, 
                int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me! it seems to be exactly what I was looking for, but I can't realize how to check if my current NumberPicker value was changed through this function.

Comment: it will give you old and new value, also I think its also checking to call this method only if there is an actual change. Like if you are continuously scrolling without break and it come to prevoius value than I think it will not be called.